# javascript midnight Date.toISOString() doesn't validate against CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ in EPUB check

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, epub, isodate

When I use new `Date().toISOString()`, it works fine, but when I set hours minutes and seconds to zero, the [EPUB validation check](http://validator.idpf.org/) tells me the following:

`"2015-09-10T14:20:09.585Z"` works fine, but `"2015-09-06T22:00:00.000Z"` yields:

> Error while parsing file 'dcterms:modified illegal syntax (expecting: 'CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ')'.

I even tried using new Date() to get current time including local timezone and then set hours, minutes and seconds (`"2015-09-10T22:00:00.192Z"`, which was not accepted either).

How do I get a valid ISO date string that is at midnight?

Comment: Do you know if 24:00:00 works?